# How do I refresh combobox item after selecting one item?

Tags: c#

My Combobox contains the name of a waiter.
When I allot the table to the selected waiter its status become true but the combobox item doesn't change.

programming on page_load:---

```
private void frmTableAllotment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        dtTmPkr.Value = System.DateTime.Now;

        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select name from waiterentry2 where status='false'", con);
        con.Open();
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            cmbWaiter.Items.Add(dr["name"]);

        }

        dr.Close();
        cmd = null;
        con.Close();

    }
```

coding on save button for waiter status= true on allot button:

```
 private void btnAllocate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
          cmd = new SqlCommand("update  waiterentry2 set status='true'  where name=@name", con);
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
          con.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is after you change the database you haven't refresh or reload the combobox databinding.

I would re factor your code as below and call the load data method after database update.

```
private void frmTableAllotment_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dtTmPkr.Value = System.DateTime.Now;
   LoadComboBox();
}

private void btnAllocate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("update  waiterentry2 set status='true'  where name=@name", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", dgvDetails.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    LoadComboBox();
}

private void LoadComboBox()
{
    while(cmbWaiter.Items.Count >0)
         cmbWaiter.Items.RemoveAt(0);

    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select name from waiterentry2 where status='false'", con);
    con.Open();
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        cmbWaiter.Items.Add(dr["name"]);
    }

    dr.Close();
    cmd = null;
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Put `cmbWaiter.Items.Clear()` into the top of `LoadComboBox()` method

Comment: Yes, Thanks @AndreyGordeev, I'm thinking that rather than adding item by item OP can directly set the datasource

Comment: @AndreyGordeev,@Damith i have done that:- cmbWaiter.Items.Clear() into the top of LoadComboBox()" but not working .. combobox shows previous item as well as new items...

Comment: sorry sorry @AndreyGordeev,@Damith i havn't seen the full coading of :- private void LoadComboBox(){} ... realyy thanks u both

Answer (score 0):

Try to call he code which you have written in form load after successful db operation in `btnAllocate_Click` event